# Pan gesture event handler in Delphi

Tags: android, gestures, delphi

I'm trying to write the pan gesture event handler in my app for Android. When I'm moving my finger fast enough over the screen I'm continuously getting OnGesture event with igiPan gesture id, but if I slow down the finger I start receiving the OnMouseMove event.

Is it a normal behavior or some issues are there? Thanks

Comment: You get the OnMouseMove event and *stop* getting the OnGesture event?

Comment: I mean I can get OnGesture event again if I will speed up the movement. It looks like events depend on the finger speed.
Also once finger is released I get the OnGesture event, even if there were OnMouseMove events in between.

Comment: It looks like events depend on the finger speed. And application will never receive OnGesture event if the finger movement is slow from the beginning.